What happens when underlying objects are deleted during an S3-to-RDS load?
Today I found myself in an interesting scenario, and I'm not quite sure what the explanation is.
There's a process that ultimately runs a bunch of queries like this
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS blah_tmp;
CREATE TABLE blah_tmp (LIKE blah INCLUDING ALL);

SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
    'blah',
    'col1,col2,col3',
    '(FORMAT csv, HEADER true)',
    aws_commons.create_s3_uri('the-bucket', 'the-prefix/the-obj-1.csv', 'us-west-2')
);

...

SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
    'blah',
    'col1,col2,col3',
    '(FORMAT csv, HEADER true)',
    aws_commons.create_s3_uri('the-bucket', 'the-prefix/the-obj-n.csv', 'us-west-2')
);

BEGIN;

DROP TABLE blah CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE blah_tmp RENAME TO blah;

COMMIT;

for the n objects from a list objects request.  Last I checked, RDS doesn't support loading all files under a prefix, so this was the solution.
One of the first ways you can imagine this would go wrong is if the objects in the prefix change before the n select statements finish -- the query is already prepared, but maybe some of the selects haven't run yet.  In real life, the objects are named with random hashes, there's another process that performs an S3 copy on a schedule into this prefix, maybe for one such table/prefix combo it takes a while to load everything, etc., so it's a real concern.
To be brief, this point of failure was addressed but assumptions become outdated and I believe that is what happened today: the selects hadn't finished, the guardrails that were in place broke, the prefix was truncated and replaced with objects named differently, all during the query execution.
Naively, I'd expect this to produce an error, but then there's a lot of nuance with how S3 treats deleted objects.  The bucket is versioned, so objects turn into delete markers and are still there in some sense.  Personally, I would still expect this to produce an error: why would RDS try to load a delete marker?  Not to mention, RDS has to be doing a GET request, and you get a 405 if you try to GET a versioned object that's a delete marker.  But maybe there's some upfront pre-computation?  Maybe it's doing a GET with a Range header?  I have no idea.
What actually happened is that there was no error or exception raised and the process, which is a Kubernetes CronJob, just kept going until it hit the active deadline and the pod was killed.  The effect of this was probably worse because the pod was killed before it had time to cancel the query and release the connection back, creating an accumulating list of database processes with no active connection to a client, all waiting to insert rows into a table that the first detached process had a lock on.
That's an aside, though, because the real question is the title:
What really is going on when underlying objects are deleted in the course of an S3-to-RDS load?
Today all signs point to RDS thinking they're worth trying to load, but I'm really not sure and I want to understand this better.
